# I just don't understand how this RoR works (upvote downvote function)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning RoR but I don't understand how the below code works. Could someone kindly explain? I am trying to understand but dont know what I miss. Especially, what I don't understand is

Why do we need  post_id while we have vote.post_id?

Why do we need upvote (boolean)?

What is the role of @success?

```
def create
    vote = Vote.new
    post_id = params[:post_id]
    vote.post_id = params[:post_id]
    vote.upvote = params[:upvote]
    vote.account_id = current_account.id
    existing_vote = Vote.where(account_id: current_account.id, post_id: post_id)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        if existing_vote.size > 0
          existing_vote.first.destroy
        else
          @success = if vote.save
                       true
                     else
                       false
                     end
        end
        @post = Post.find(post_id)
        render 'votes/create'
      end
    end
  end
```

```
    def score
      if self.upvotes > 0 || self.downvotes > 0
        self.upvotes > 0 ? (self.upvotes - self.downvotes) : (self.downvotes * -1)
      else
        0
      end
    end
```

```
$(function () {
  $(".vote").on("click", ".upvote", function () {
    let post_id = $(this).parent().data("id"),
     is_upvote = $(this).hasClass("upvote")
    console.log("clicked " + post_id );

    $.ajax({
      url: "post/vote",
      type:'POST',
      data: { post_id: post_id, upvote: is_upvote },
      success: function(){
        console.log("success");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```
<div id="vote-actions-<%= post.id%>" class="vote" data-id="<%= post.id%>" >
      <div class="fa fa-arrow-up upvote"> </div>
      <div class="font-weight-bold score"><%= post.score%></div>
      <div class="fa fa-arrow-down downvote"> </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#vote-actions-<%=@post.id%> .score").text(<%= @post.score%>)
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this code? There are some things going on there that are not very good practice. The whole `if save then true ...` is useless, `save` returns `true` or `false`, no need for the if statement

Comment: `def score` can be rewritten as just `upvotes.to_i - downvotes.to_i`

Comment: Thank you sir. This code came from the reddit clone tutorial on youtube. I just try to follow it and learn something but there's many question because I don't have a good foundation of ruby or rails. Appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: I would suggest you follow a proven tutorial instead of some random code you see, there is a lot of stuff out there that is not very helpful. Google `rails hartl tutorial`, that's the gold standard in Rails tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering yours doubts one by one:

1. by post_id = params[:post_id], we are simply storing the params value to a local variable that can be used for later task like we did in "Vote.where(account_id: current_account.id, post_id: post_id)", while via
   vote = Vote.new
   vote.post_id = params[:post_id]

we are creating a new instance of class vote and assigning params value to its post_id attribute.

2. since we are dealing with switching conditions here with possible values 0 and 1, so code is having upvote as bool, It can be changed to Int too based on need.
3. @ refer a "instance variable", that would be available to the view partial of "create" method or can be used to flash messages etc.

Comment: Appreciate your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `post_id` just giving you a shorthand so you don't have to retype `params[:post_id]` everywhere.

`upvote` seems a little redundant because the click handler is only going to operate on items with the `.upvote` class. I could be wrong but it seems to me you could just as easily remove the redundant upvote check and replace your data with `{ post_id: post_id, upvote: true }`. Is there a complementary downvote function, or is this intended to toggle between voted states?

`@succes` also seems extraneous in this context unless it's being used somewhere else in the view; I don't see it serving an immediate purpose.

Comment: Thank you sir. There will be a downvote function. However, before that, I dont know why I need upvote boolean here (why do we need to post boolean to make the button work)